# How to copy data from an a csv to Azure SQL Server table?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataset based on a csv file. This exposes a data as follows:

```
Name,Age
John,23
```

I have an Azure SQL Server instance with a table named: [People]
This has columns

Name, Age

I am using the Copy Data task activity and trying to copy data from the csv data set into the azure table. 
There is no option to indicate the table name as a source. Instead I have a space to input a Stored Procedure name?

How does this work? Where do I put the target table name in the image below?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should DEFINITELY have a table name to write to.  If you don't have a table, something is wrong with your setup.  Anyway, make sure you have a table to write to; make sure the field names in your table match the fields in the CSV file.  Then, follow the steps outlined in the description below.  There are several steps to click through, but all are pretty intuitive, so just follow the instructions step by step and you should be fine.

http://normalian.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/09/04/233320

Answer (score 0):

You can add records into the SQL Database table directly without stored procedures, by configuring the table value on the **Sink Dataset** rather than the **Copy Activity** which is what is happening.

Have a look at the below screenshot which shows the **Table** field within my dataset.

[image]

Comment: my dataset is already designed and points to a csv. I cannot have the dataset to table as suggested. Thanks

Comment: I meant your Sink Dataset. I believe it needs to be point to a SQL DB table correct?

Comment: Same issue. Both source and target have been set up. I just have to move data between the two. However thanks for your clarification. Found the steps involved creating a SQL table Type matching the structure of the target tables and then using this in the stored procedure to to populate the target table. I will write up the details later.